# select statement with where condition (select all or some)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to following tables:

images:

```
imageID    userId    Translated    theImage
--------------------------------------------
    1         2         1           image1
    2         3         0           image2
    3         3         0           image3 
    4         3         0           image4
    5         3         1           image5
```

and translationChains:

```
imageID    sourceLang    targetLang
------------------------------------
   1           2            3
   2           4            1
   3           5            1
   4           4            2
   5           1            4
```

now I have two options:
I want either to choose all the images the wasn't translated for a specific user in any language
or to choose all the images for this user that wasn't translated in a specific language.

I have the following query for the first option:

```
"Select images.imageid, images.theimage, images.translationRating 
From images where images.userID=? And images.translated =0"
```

and for the second option I have:

```
"Select images.imageid, images.theimage, images.translationRating 
From images, translationchains  
where images.userID=? And images.translated =0 and
translationchains.imageId = images.imageid
and translationchains.targetLang = ? "
```

for example if i'll use the first query with user 3 I want the result to be:

```
2         3         0           image2
3         3         0           image3 
4         3         0           image4
```

and for the second query with user 3 and targerLang = 1 I want the result to be:

```
    2         3         0           image2
    3         3         0           image3
```

I want to combine this two queries into one query that will work in all cases (according to the parameters that i'll send)

how can I do it?

I was trying to send as the second parameter (translationchains.targetLang = ?) the string " " (empty string) so it will ignore this condition but it didn't work

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: rows from the 'images' table,
in the first option I don't care about the image Lang (lang=all)
in the second option I want all the rows where in the 'translationChains' table the targetLang is X

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

**FIRST  query**

```
      Select * From images where userID=3 And translated =0
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a37eb/4)

OUTPUT:

```
  imageID   userId  Translated  theImage 
   2          3          0      image2
   3          3          0      image3
   4          3          0      image4
```

**SECOND query**

```
   Select i.imageID, userId, Translated, theImage 
   From images i
   inner join translationchains  t
   on t.imageId = i.imageid
   where i.userID=3 And i.translated =0 
   and t.targetLang = 1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a37eb/9)

OUTPUT:

```
 imageID    userId  Translated  theImage 
    2         3         0       image2
    3         3         0       image3
```

THE COMBINE:

```
 Select i.imageID, userId, Translated, theImage 
 From images i
 inner join translationchains  t
 on t.imageId = i.imageid
 where i.userID=3 And i.translated =0 
 and t.targetLang in (select targetLang from translationChains  )
                                ^^^^^-------replace this by 1 or 2 or 3 or let it like that for all

    //-- if you want change targetLang just replace it by any number
    //--like that (select 1 from translationChains  )
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a37eb/19)

OBS: you could also do it in php when you select the language then you put

```
   $sql .= "AND t.targetLang = the_id_selected_of_language ";
```

Comment: tnx, but this is similar to what I wrote, I want a one query for both cases - with a special parameter or similar thing

Comment: nice that it solved your problem make sure to accept answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
SELECT images.imageid, images.theimage, images.translationRating 
FROM images
INNER JOIN translationchains ON translationchains.imageId = images.imageid
WHERE images.userID=? 
AND (
    (images.translated =1 AND translationchains.targetLang = ?) 
    OR (images.translated =0)
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because in the first 'And' condition I also need it to be images.translated =0  which means that anyway it returns images.translated =0 without checking for the targetLang

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
SELECT a.imageid, a.theimage , a.translationRating
FROM images a , translationchains b
WHERE a.imageId = b.imageid
AND a.translated = 0
GROUP BY b.targetLang
```

The above query will be group the result based on the target language

Comment: and them what? I need to either choose one targetLang or choose them all